# Why can't I use @file:Repository and @file:DependsOn in .kts kotlin script?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

I see examples online where a .kts file begins with things like

```
@file:Repository(<some-maven-repo-url>)
@file:DependsOn(<some-dependency-identifier)
```

But I can't get it to work for my `helloworld.kts` file.

```
helloworld.kts:1:7: error: unresolved reference: Repository
@file:Repository(...)
      ^
helloworld.kts:2:7: error: unresolved reference: DependsOn
@file:DependsOn(...)
      ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work, the file name must end in `.main.kts`. For the OP example it would need to be `helloworld.main.kts`.